# How to define behavior that is executed in case of a command-parsing error using CommandLineUtils ExecuteAsync?

Tags: c#, parsing, console-application, command-line-arguments, commandlineutils

On execution, my program takes two arguments it needs to run

```
static Task<int> Main(string[] args)
{
   return CommandLineApplication.ExecuteAsync<MyUpdateService>(args);
}

[Argument(0, Description = "Filepath")]
     
private string Filepath { get; }

[Argument(1, Description = "UpdateMode")]

private int Mode { get; }
```

I'm using this package:

https://github.com/natemcmaster/CommandLineUtils

I want to show a messagebox in case the program is run with too few/ too many arguments, or the arguments don't match the required types (1: string, 2: int).

Since this cannot be achieved by simply wrapping a try/catch-block around it: Can it be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this is surprisingly simple, I just didn't see it...

For anyone who is working on this problem:

```
public static Task<int> Main(string[] args)
{
    try
    {
        //if program is run without command-line arguments
        if (args == null || args.Length == 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        }
        //if program is run with more or less than 2 arguments
        else if (args.Length != 2)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
        }
        //if - for example - the second argument cannot be parsed to an int
        else if (!int.TryParse(args[1], out int result))
        {
            throw new ArrayTypeMismatchException();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        string errorMsg = "This app cannot be executed direclty.";

        if (ex is ArgumentOutOfRangeException || ex is ArrayTypeMismatchException)
        {
            errorMsg = "Exception error: This app needs a different set of arguments to execute.";
        }
        new CustomMessageBox().Show(errorMsg);
        return Task.FromResult(1);
    }

    return CommandLineApplication.ExecuteAsync<MyUpdateService>(args);
}

[Required, Argument(0, Description = "Filepath")]

private string IniFilepath { get; }

[Required, Argument(1, Description = "UpdateMode")]

private int Mode { get; }
```